# having problems with context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

i understand context and the ability to pass state down without prop drilling (to me it honestly seems like the same amount of work... i was using redux for global state management and besides the boilerplate the ability to use reducers, action creators, AND the redux dev tools makes it seem way more useful to me)

even using useContext hook the amount of code required is really the same fricking thing as just prop drilling to me... but maybe i'm missing something

ALL that aside.. i am currently trying to have a simple nav bar feature where when a burger menu is opened the backdrop of the home page turns to a faded darker opacity. i don't want a library. i like to do this all myself.

this is my App file. i was assuming i could just pass the state down (open) which would indicate if the nav is open. BUT HOW can i change the state of open IF THE only thing i can pass is open and not setOpen... i cant have an onClick event on the entire Nav bar component. i need the onclick even to be in the Nav, but all that is being passed is the state itself. every time i think i understand react some new unique situation comes up where i run into similar problems with state

```
// components
import Nav from './components/Nav'
import Homepage from './components/Homepage'
import React, {useState, createContext} from "react";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

// pages
import About from './components/pages/About'
import Stories from './components/pages/Stories'
import News from './components/pages/News'
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext';




// imports
function App() {
  const [open, setOpen]=useState(false)

  return (
    <>
<Router>

  <ThemeContext.Provider value={open}>
    <Nav />
  <Route path='/' exact>
    <Homepage />

  </Route>

  <Route path='/about' component={About} exact />
  <Route path='/stories' component={Stories} exact />
  <Route path='/news' component={News} exact />
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
</Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here is my nav component

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useContext, useRef} from 'react'
import '../styles/custom.css'
import MenuDrop from './MenuDrop.js'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import ThemeContext from '../ThemeContext.js'

const Nav = () => {
  const [active, setActive]=useState(false)
  const [touched, setTouched]=useState(false)

  const myRef=useRef()

  const open=useContext(ThemeContext)

const clicker=()=>{
  if(window.innerWidth<450){
  setActive(!active);

}
}

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(open)
},[active])



const toucher=()=>{
  setTouched(true);
}

const toucherOff=()=>{
  setTouched(false);
}

  return (
/*  NAVBAR */
<>
<div className={`shadow-xl ${open?'dark':'light'}`}>
    <div  className='nav c overflow-hidden w-full nav-main md:pt-8 pt-4  flex  justify-between md:justify-around items-center flex-row flex-shadow-2xl'>
        <h1 className=' mx-2   antialiased  text-lg md:text-3xl font-bold text-green-700 font-second-bold'>HUNTER SOLICITERS</h1>
        <div className={`${active?'nav-items-active':'nav-items'} bg-white items-center  md:items-center flex flex-col justify-center md:flex-row md:justify-around list-none w-1/3   flex-shadow-2xl`}>
        <Link onClick={()=>setActive(false)} to='/about' className='lg:mt-0 mt-20 text-green-800 hover:text-green-800 font-semibold duration-200 antialiased  p-2 cursor-pointer lg:my-0 my-6 text-sm lg:hover:text-white lg:hover:bg-red-900 font-main'>About</Link>
        <li onClick={()=>setActive(false)} className='text-green-800 hover:text-green-800 font-semibold duration-200 antialiased  p-2 cursor-pointer lg:my-0 my-6 text-sm lg:hover:text-white lg:hover:bg-red-900 font-main'>Contact</li>
        <Link onClick={()=>setActive(false)} to='/stories' className='lg:mt-0  text-green-800 hover:text-green-800 font-semibold duration-200 antialiased  p-2 cursor-pointer lg:my-0 my-6 text-sm lg:hover:text-white lg:hover:bg-red-900 font-main'>Stories</Link>
        <Link onClick={()=>setActive(false)} to='/news' className='lg:mt-0  text-green-800 hover:text-green-800 font-semibold duration-200 antialiased  p-2 cursor-pointer lg:my-0 my-6 text-sm lg:hover:text-white lg:hover:bg-red-900 font-main'>News</Link>
        <div onMouseLeave={()=>toucherOff()} onMouseEnter={()=>setTouched(true)} className='flex   flex-row items-center'>
        <li  onClick={()=>setActive(false)} className='text-green-800 hover:text-green-800 font-semibold duration-200 antialiased  p-2 cursor-pointer lg:my-0 my-6 text-sm lg:hover:text-white lg:hover:bg-red-900 font-main'>Team</li>
        <svg  className='hover:bg-red-900 text-black hover:text-white arrowTwo' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7" />
          </svg>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div onClick={()=>clicker()} ref={myRef} className={active?'mx-2 burger-active ':'burger mx-2'}>
    <div className={active?'toggle1 line-one':'line-one'}></div>
    <div className={active?' toggle2 line-two':'line-two'}></div>
    <div className={active?' toggle3 line-three':'line-three'}></div>
    </div>

    </div>
<MenuDrop toucher={toucher} setTouched={setTouched} toucherOff={toucherOff} touched={touched}/>
</div>
      </>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

and here is my homepage component

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
// COMPONENTS
import Banner from './Banner'
import Footer from './Footer'
import GreenBanner from './GreenBanner'
import HomepageContentCards from './HomepageContentCards'
import HomepageContent from './HomepageContent'
import HomepageTeam from './HomepageTeam'
import WrappedMap from './Map'
import ThemeContext from '../ThemeContext'
import '../styles/custom.css'

// ASSETS
import imageTwo from '../images/home-image-two.jpg'
import imageThree from '../images/home-image-three.jpg'
import imageFour from '../images/home-image-four.jpg'

const Homepage = () => {
  useEffect(()=>{
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    console.log(open)
})

const open=useContext(ThemeContext)
  return (
<div className={`${open==='false'?'mt-0':'mt-20'} bg-container mt-10 md:mt-0 shadow-2xl`}>
    <Banner />
<div className='shadow-xl grid grid-cols-1 gap-0 lg:gap-0 lg:grid-cols-12'>
  <div class=" col-span-7">
    <HomepageContent />
        </div>
  <div class="">
    <HomepageTeam />
  </div>
    </div>
    <GreenBanner />
  <div className='grid grid-cols-1 gap-2 lg:gap-3 sm:grid-cols-3'>
    <HomepageContentCards image={imageTwo}/>
    <HomepageContentCards image={imageThree} />
    <HomepageContentCards image={imageFour} />
  </div>


  <div className='mt-8 lg:mt-0'>
    <WrappedMap
    isMarkerShown
    googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places$key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY}`}
    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    />
  </div>

    <Footer />

    </div>
  )
}

export default Homepage
```

im using tailwind so ignore all the classes etc. basically im trying to have a simple state (whether the nav bar is open and burger has been pressed to open it or not).... if it is open the rest of the background stuff (homepage) becomes a dark color to faded opacity by using conditional rendering-->open?'dark':'light'

i can hand the state down but how do i pass the function (setOpen) from the hook down or how can i change the state from a child component if the state and hook is created in the above parent component (App)

i swear react makes state management silly AF sometime to me

Comment: You can just pass down an object containing both the state value and the set function as your context value.

Comment: thanks man. ended up doing this in my initial createContext file ```import React from 'react';



const ThemeContext = React.createContext({open:null, setOpen:null});

export default ThemeContext;```   then i set those later in the  App component with this ```  const [open, setOpen]=useState(false)
  const ok=useContext(ThemeContext)

  return (
    <>
<Router>

  <ThemeContext.Provider value={{open, setOpen}}>```